# is it possible to extend multiple templates in Azure devops in different checkout repos?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two templates in different reposteries, can I extend my triggering YAML to extend to both

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: modules1
      type: githubenterprise
      endpoint: GitHubent
      ref: refs/tags/v1.3.1.3
      name: xxxxaip/terra-modules

    - repository: modules2
      type: githubent
      endpoint: GitHubent
      ref: refs/tags/v1.3.1.3
      name: xxxxaip/yaml-modules

extends:



  template: pipeline/stages/lookout1.yml@modules1


  template: pipeline/stages/lookout2.yml@modules2
```

Is it possible to declare template like two times or is there any other way around?

Comment: You can extend one template. However you can *include* as many templates as you want by importing the template in the appropriate scope. If you want additional help, you'll have to explain in more detail what each of these templates does and why you want to extend both of them.

Comment: i have one template to execute in one repo and other in second repo, but the source code is stored in same repo (code is common but need to pass to two templates which are in different repo,) Please let me know

Comment: I'm asking what those templates *do*. You can't extend both of them, you can only extend one. You'll probably need to restructure things a bit and extract the relevant jobs so you can import them as a job template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined two different templates in one repo and extended to that repo, which is a workaround, but thanks for confirming it can be done like i was trying

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you could look into this document for more references. [Templates - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#insert-a-template)

Within this document, multiple templates could be declared at different yaml levels.

***Steps reuse:***

```
jobs:
- job: Linux
 pool:
   vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
 steps:
 - template: templates/include-npm-steps.yml  # Template reference
- job: Windows
 pool:
   vmImage: 'windows-latest'
 steps:
 - template: templates/include-npm-steps.yml
```

***Jobs reuse:***

```
jobs:
- template: templates/jobs.yml  # Template reference
- template: templates/jobs.yml  # Template reference
- template: templates/jobs.yml  # Template reference
```

***Stages reuse:***

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
- main
pool:
 vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
stages:
- stage: Install
 jobs: 
 - job: npminstall
   steps:
   - task: Npm@1
     inputs:
       command: 'install'
- template: templates/stages1.yml # Template reference
- template: templates/stages2.yml # Template reference
```